# Is it possible to refer to an attribute of an object though multiple layers in Python?

Tags: python, object, oop

Say I have these classes

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, area: int, house_number: int):
        self.area = area
        self.house_number = house_number


class Neighborhood:
    def __init__(self):
        self.neighborhood = [House]


class City:
    def __init__(self):
        self.city = [Neighborhood]
```

Am I able to refer to the house_number of any house in the city when I have an object of type City?
If yes, how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, these two lines probably don't mean what you think they mean:

```py
        self.neighborhood = [House]
...
        self.city = [Neighborhood]
```

In Python, `[House]` does not mean "a list of House objects". It means "a list containing one element, which is the `House` class". Python does not enforce type constraints on lists, but you can add [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) like this:

```py
from typing import List
...
        self.houses: List[House] = []
```

Note that this will not prevent you from doing `self.houses.append("a string")`, but a good IDE like PyCharm will display a warning. I also changed your variable name to something more intuitive (`houses` is a good name for a list of `House` objects).

Moving on to your actual question, suppose that we have the following classes:

```py
from typing import List


class House:
    def __init__(self, area: int, house_number: int):
        self.area = area
        self.house_number = house_number


class Neighborhood:
    def __init__(self):
        self.houses: List[House] = []


class City:
    def __init__(self):
        self.neighborhoods: List[Neighborhood] = []
```

Now, given an instance of `City`, you can access all of the house numbers like this:

```py
chicago = City()
lakeview = Neighborhood()
chicago.neighborhoods.append(lakeview)
lakeview.houses.append(House(2000, 5))
lakeview.houses.append(House(3000, 17))

for neighborhood in chicago.neighborhoods:
    for house in neighborhood.houses:
        print(house.house_number)
```

Now you can place this code in a method on the `City` class, put the numbers in a list, or do anything you like.